# Is it possible to use Boot2Docker without VT-x?

Tags: virtualbox, docker, boot2docker

I want to use Docker on a machine that has VT-x disabled (and cannot be enabled). Is this possible?

I'm using [Boot2Docker](http://boot2docker.io/) on Windows 7 x64, there's no mention of requirements there, or in the [Docker instructions](http://docs.docker.com/installation/windows/) either.

I get this output from Boot2Docker start:

```
Welcome to Git (version 1.9.0-preview20140217)


Run 'git help git' to display the help index.
Run 'git help <command>' to display help for specific commands.
initialising...
2014/06/20 08:43:04 executing: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe showvminfo boot2docker-vm --machinereadable
2014/06/20 08:43:05 Virtual machine boot2docker-vm already exists
starting...
2014/06/20 08:43:05 executing: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe showvminfo boot2docker-vm --machinereadable
2014/06/20 08:43:05 executing: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe startvm boot2docker-vm --type headless
Waiting for VM "boot2docker-vm" to power on...
VBoxManage.exe: error: VT-x is disabled in the BIOS. (VERR_VMX_MSR_VMXON_DISABLED)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component Console, interface IConsole
2014/06/20 08:43:06 executing: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe showvminfo boot2docker-vm --machinereadable
2014/06/20 08:43:06 Failed to start machine "boot2docker-vm" (run again with -v for details)
connecting...
2014/06/20 08:43:06 Failed to get machine "boot2docker-vm": exit status 1
```

Is it possible, or is there a workaround with VirtualBox settings that can make it work?

Comment: https://stefanscherer.github.io/how-to-create-a-32bit-boot2docker-for-x86-cpus/ shows that it is possible (although using an old docker version), but I am getting a kernel panic when starting the 32 bits boot2docker iso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not possible.  I'm stuck with a similar situation with a Q8200 core 2 duo.  Doesn't support VT-x which flat out means no 64 bit virtual machines.  Doesn't matter which stack.

Answer (score 2):

You can fill a bug report on github: https://github.com/boot2docker/windows-installer. boot2docker should not require VT-x.

In the meantime, you can switch to any other os, like CoreOS (lightweight, docker already installed) or raw ubuntu then install docker.

You might as well want to take a look at Vagrant. CoreOS provides vagrantfiles and it is as easy as `vagrant up` to spawn a VM with docker enabled.

Comment: You'd need to make sure to use a 32-bit guest OS

Comment: Hmmm? Docker does not support 32bit. Did you mean 64?

Comment: Nope, VT-X is **required** for 64-bit guests.

"In order to be able to run a 64-Bit system in a VirtualBox, you need a cpu which supports virtualization. AMD calls this function AMD-V, Intel uses VT-x."

from: http://askubuntu.com/questions/41550/how-do-i-run-a-64-bit-guest-in-virtualbox

Comment: Wasn't aware of this limitation. Will be an issue then as Docker is 64bits only.

Comment: I'm always amused when someone suggests switching OS for a single tool. So... Docker is 64-bit only, and VirtualBox only supports x64 with VT-x. I've just tried the ISO with VMWare Player with a similar failure.